# Memory usage when passing by reference?

Tags: c++

I have an object (i.e. an image) that takes up 1MB of memory.
I pass this image into a function, which modifies it.
If I pass this image into the function by reference, would the entire 1MB be copied, or just its place in memory?

Comment: The terminology itself says exactly what it does..

Comment: C does not have references - so I removed the C tag.  C++ does have references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing by reference creates an alias to the object.  The only memory used is the stack space allocated to hold the alias.

Comment: Is the 'alias' ever anything other than a pointer in disguise?  (The disguise being that you don't need to use the pointer dereferencing notation to access the object behind the reference.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, it can be *nothing* instead of a pointer.

Comment: Yes, but the disguise covers also, that one cannot have a null reference and once created reference to some object cannot be changed to point at something else.

Comment: You can have a null ref ex 

void TakeAnA(A &ref)
{

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 A* ptr= nullptr; 
 TakeAnA(*ptr);
}

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'it can be _nothing_ instead of a pointer'?  About the only context in which I can think that might hold is if you have a reference created to another variable already in scope: `int a; int &b = a;` where there needn't be a pointer explicitly created.  But the question context was 'passing to a function by reference', and this does not apply in such a context, does it?

Comment: @rerun: oh, not this again. **Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour.**

Comment: @Jonathan: if the function gets inlined, the situation is very similar to the one you describe, and the compiler can discard the reference.

Comment: Yes its a contrived example and will crash in almost all cases before it gets to the function.  The one exception I have seen is when you call a member function on a nullptr to a class.

Answer (score 13):

No just a pointer - a reference is just a pointer with fancy syntax so it doesn't scare the children.

Comment: +1 for scaring the children... I bet they deserved it though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just the reference location to the object would be passed onto the stack.

Just so we're clear here, this only applies to C++.  In C, you always pass by value.  You can mimic pass-by-reference by passing in pointer locations (which is how references in C++ work anyway, if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 2):

When you pass by reference you don't copy the object but only the reference to the object. That's the whole point of passing by reference.

Answer (score 1):

just the reference to the image object is sent to the function, not the whole image.